# Too much nesting in ruby?

Tags: ruby, nested

Surely there must be a better way of doing this:

```rb
File.open('Data/Networks/to_process.txt', 'w') do |out|
  Dir['Data/Networks/*'].each do |f|
    if File.directory?(f)
      File.open("#{f}/list.txt").each do |line|
        out.puts File.basename(f) + "/" + line.split(" ")[0]
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Cheers!

Comment: You could at least provides comments to describe what you are doing there.

Comment: Data/Networks/___/list.txt contains a list of lines in the format: "SOMEHASH SOMEOTHERVALUE". I want to compile a list of "___/SOMEHASH" to Data/Networks/to_process.txt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're looking for a particular file in each of the directories, just let `Dir#[]` find them for you, completely eliminating the need to check for a directory. In addition, `IO#puts` will accept an array, putting each element on a new line. This will get rid of another level of nesting.

```
File.open('Data/Networks/to_process.txt', 'w') do |out|
  Dir['Data/Networks/*/list.txt'] do |file|
    dir = File.basename(File.dirname(file))
    out.puts File.readlines(file).map { |l| "#{dir}/#{l.split.first}" }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 8):

You can rid of 1 level of nesting by utilizing Guard Clause pattern:

```
File.open('Data/Networks/to_process.txt', 'w') do |out|
  Dir['Data/Networks/*'].each do |f|
    next unless File.directory?(f)
    File.open("#{f}/list.txt").each do |line|
      out.puts File.basename(f) + "/" + line.split(" ")[0]
    end
  end
end
```

See [Jeff Atwood's article](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/01/flattening-arrow-code.html) on this approach.

Answer (score 6):

IMHO there's nothing wrong with your code, but you could do the directory globbing and the check from the `if` in one statement, saving one level of nesting:

```
Dir.glob('Data/Networks/*').select { |fn| File.directory?(fn) }.each do |f|
  ...
end
```

Comment: Expressing it as a series of transforms like this is often more readable than a series of nested statements.

Comment: @tadman: As somebody who does quite a bit of FP I agree on the series of transforms things, but I still think that OP's code was readable enough as is, especially since my line is rather long. IMHO DNNX's answer is the sweet spot here.

Comment: The Guard Pattern is a good fit for this case, indeed, though knowing more than one trick is always handy.

Answer (score 1):

Reducing the nesting a bit by separating the input from the output:

```
directories = Dir['Data/Networks/*'].find_all{|f| File.directory?(f)}
output_lines = directories.flat_map do |f|
  output_lines_for_directory = File.open("#{f}/list.txt").map do |line|
    File.basename(f) + "/" + line.split(" ")[0]
  end
end
File.open('Data/Networks/to_process.txt', 'w') do |out|
  out.puts output_lines.join("\n")
end
```